# itunes like java look and feel

Tags: swing, itunes

I need to build a swing application that looks exactly like itunes player in Mac.my java app should run on all operating systems with same itunes like look and feel
what is the swing library used to customize the look and feel of itunes original application?
is there a java laf library that mimics itunes laf?

thanks

Comment: As if Carbon wasn't a bad enough framework...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no Java LnF library that mimics iTunes.

Consider [seaglass](http://code.google.com/p/seaglass/) look and feel - it is pretty mac-ish and is straight forward to use.
Or you may create your Swing components using [macwidgets](http://code.google.com/p/macwidgets/) project